# Image Path When Using CSS to style UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, css, ios, uiwebview

I am loading a CSS file to style a UIWebView. I would like to have an inline "play" button when the CSS detects a video. I have it working except it is not loading the image (it is loading the image placeholder but not the image). I'm using the following CSS:

```
span.vvqbox:after { content:url(watchvideo.png) }
```

The .css file is in the same directory as the .png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are loading a local html file (that loads a local css file) and you are using the `- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL` method of UIWebView you will need to set the baseURL to your bundle so the webview knows where to load the images.

```
[webview loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]];
```